# How do I paint Swing Components to a PDF file with iText?

Tags: java, swing, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I would like to print my Swing JComponent via iText to pdf.

```
JComponent com = new JPanel();
com.add( new JLabel("hello") );

PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( dFile ) );
document.open( );

PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent( );
PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate( pageImageableWidth, pageImageableHeight );
Graphics2D g2d = tp.createGraphics( pageImageableWidth, pageImageableHeight, new DefaultFontMapper( ) );
g2d.translate( pf.getImageableX( ), pf.getImageableY( ) );
g2d.scale( 0.4d, 0.4d );
com.paint( g2d );
cb.addTemplate( tp, 25, 200 );
g2d.dispose( );
```

Unfortunately nothing is shown in the PDF file.
Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured it out adding addNotify and validate helps.

```
    com.addNotify( );
    com.validate( );
```

Comment: Yes. JavaDoc of addNotify() says it "should not be called directly by programs", but in practice, it is necessary in headless context (exporting without a GUI). Otherwise, the children of the component are not laid out and keep a size of zero.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to call

```
com.addNotify()
com.setSize()
com.validate()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that much about iText, but... you did close the `PdfWriter` at some point, right?