# How to show an image appearing on JPanel in PDF

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I have written a Java code, which shows a line chart on a `JPanel` on clicking a button. What I want is to show that line chart in my PDF file, using the Java PDF library, [itextpdf](http://itextpdf.com/). The problem is that there is no image of pie chart created in a folder. I can easily paste an existing image, e.g. a pie chart, in a PDF file. So in this scenario (when I don't have any image file of a pie chart), give me an idea how to show this chart in a PDF.

Comment: Not knowing which PDF library you're using it's hard to answer exactly, but you can [make a JPanel render its contents into an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349220/convert-jpanel-to-image). Then you might be able to use the resulting BufferedImage directly in your PDF library, or you can write its contents into a temporary file using [`ImageIO.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

Answer (score 1):

May be one of these could help

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2006/jw-1209-swing.html

or

[How do I paint Swing Components to a PDF file with iText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425590/how-do-i-paint-swing-components-to-a-pdf-file-with-itext)

Answer (score -2):

There are lots of commercial and Open Source PDF viewers for Java. What is wrong with them?