# MiG Layout to iText PDF

Tags: java, swing, itext, miglayout

I want to export a document created in my program (made out of JPanels, JTextAreas, JLabels, etc...) into a pdf using iText library.

I will manually recreate the whole look of my document in iText and that is where I come to a problem.

In order for them to be to 1:1 to scale, I'll visually compare the two as I'm writting the code, hardcoding any spacing, height and such.

However, I want to know which unit to use in MiG so that when somebody runs my program in a different resolution doesn't get deifferent results.

Ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just put the image of your GUI component into the PDF directly? Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425590/how-do-i-paint-swing-components-to-a-pdf-file-with-itext

Comment: I don't really want EXACT copy, I just want the text to be same font, size and position.