# Retrieve Image From JLabel and store it in a variable in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jlabel

How do I retrieve an my image that has been fetched from mysql database and store it in a variable?

The image retrieved from the database is as follows:

```
byte[] imageData = rs.getBytes("Image");
format = new ImageIcon(imageData);
lblimg.setIcon(format);
```

Now what I want to do, to store the `lblimg` into a variable. Then I can use the variable which contains the image to add in a pdf file.

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("Report.pdf"));
doc.open();

doc.add(new Paragraph( // img to be added here ));
```

Please help me to achieve that. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to print in the PDF file ? The `Image` or the `JLabel` containing the image ?

Comment: @blackbishop - I want to print the JLable containing the image in the PDF.

Comment: Please take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425590/how-do-i-paint-swing-components-to-a-pdf-file-with-itext)

Comment: @blackbishop Unfortunately I cannot understand this post :/