# Retrieve time from MySQL database & populate JSpinner in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jspinner

How do I retrieve the time format from a MySQL database and use it to populate a `JSpinner` in Java? The `JSpinner` should be populated when I click the 'NEXT' button. The code I am currently using is as follows:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24); // 24 == 12 PM == 00:00:00
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
    model.setValue(calendar.getTime());

    spinner = new JSpinner(model);
    JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinner, "HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
    formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false); 
    formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);

    spinner.setEditor(editor);
    spinner.setBounds(419, 218, 119, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(spinner);

    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    if(rs.next()){
                    String time = rs.getString("Time");
                    spinner.setValue(time); // This is not working
                ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SpinnerDateModel` as a model for your `JSpinner` and it uses a `Date` type, but your are trying to set a `String` value.

I think you need to format it to `Date` before you set the value of your `spinner` :

```
String time = rs.getString("Time");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
spinner.setValue(format.parseObject(time));
```

Comment: This works man ! Thank you loads :)
If you don't mind, can you have a look at this question ? :/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644685/retrieve-image-from-jlabel-and-store-it-in-a-variable-in-java

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.. What if I want to clear or reset the spinner to 00:00:00 ? How do I achieve that?

Comment: Create `String reset = "00:00:00"`, format it and set the value as shown in the code above.